# Fit column width to text shortcut?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2007

I know that I can double-click a column header with my mouse, but is there a keyboard shortcut to fit a column to the text width?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select all by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>.

Comment: This answer is the better one now because it doesn't come with a warning that your shortcut is old, and it shows you where the new menu items actually are.

Answer (score 12):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> one after the other.

Comment: Ctrl + Spacebar first.

Comment: If you don't have the correct cell selected you can select the whole row with Ctrl + Spacebar as snitzr mentioned.