# Keyboard Shortcut to Fit Column Width to Text in Mac Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, office-for-mac, microsoft-excel-2011

On a PC this is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd>, as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/289132/fit-column-width-to-text-shortcut).

Is there an equivalent keyboard shortcut in Excel for Mac, to **fit the column width to the width of the text**?

I'm using the 2011 version.

Comment: I don't have my Macbook with me so I can't confirm if this is possible, but have you tried [assigning a custom keyboard shortcut](http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/12/en-us/excel/item/37dfe7e2-8158-45c1-8556-ec1cbd343f4d) to it? I believe [Autofit Column Width](http://excelsemipro.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Create-Keyboard-Shortcuts-Undo.jpg) should be under Format.

Comment: Thanks for a good idea! Unfortunately 'Autofit Column Width' wasn't in there (under 'Format'). I set a shortcut that pops a window asking me to type a width in inches. I'm still looking for an Autofit solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although Microsoft did not include many keyboard shortcuts in their Office Suite for Mac, you can make your own for any app including Office apps.  To do so:

- Go to **System Preferences** and then **Keyboard**.
- Select the shortcuts tab.
- You can add any shortcut there either system-wide for any application or application specific by clicking the Plus button <kbd>+</kbd>, selecting Excel and recording your key combination.

In this case you must type in `AutoFit Selection` just as it appears on the menu in Excel. (Format > Column > AutoFit Selection)

You can choose any key combination that suits your fancy.

[image: System Preferences Keyboard Shortcuts]

Comment: In newer MS Excel, the menu in excel is named "Auto-fit Selection"